# How should the server for a single-page application handle expired oAuth tokens?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

As background, I'm using the Google OAuth2 NodeJS client, but I think my question is more abstract / technology independent.

My website is single-page application that communicates via AJAX to the server.

When a user first visits my website, I perform an OAuth2 flow which redirects them to Google to log in, and then redirects back to my site with an access token. I store this access token in a cookie, and use it to handle various calls made to the server via AJAX.

My challenge is that I'm unsure what to do when that access_token expires. Should I be storing the refresh_token in a cookie as well, and using that, or are there security issues in doing so?

Should I be redirecting the browser to perform the login flow again? That seems fairly ugly for a single-page application.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the OAuth2 flow via js in the background(like the login flow with the popup window), and if the access hasn't been revoked for you app id, then the user shouldn't see anything about it. Although you can set a hint on the user email to authenticate, this may not work.
The other way that you mentioned, is the refresh token, that you can use to ask for a new access token, without user interaction. Maybe that would be the better idea, but remember, that you will only get a refresh token if you set the `access type` to offline.